# Graphlab and numpy issue

Tags: python, numpy, graphlab

I'm currently doing a course on Coursera (Machine Leraning) offered by University of Washington and I'm facing little problem with the `numpy` and `graphlab`

The course requests to use a version of `graphlab` higher than 1.7
Mine is higher as you can see below, however, when I run the script below, I got an error as follows:

```
  [INFO] graphlab.cython.cy_server: GraphLab Create v2.1 started.
  def get_numpy_data(data_sframe, features, output):
      data_sframe['constant'] = 1
      features = ['constant'] + features # this is how you combine two lists
      # the following line will convert the features_SFrame into a numpy matrix:
      feature_matrix = features_sframe.to_numpy()
      # assign the column of data_sframe associated with the output to the SArray output_sarray

      # the following will convert the SArray into a numpy array by first converting it to a list
      output_array = output_sarray.to_numpy()
      return(feature_matrix, output_array)

     (example_features, example_output) = get_numpy_data(sales,['sqft_living'], 'price') # the [] around 'sqft_living' makes it a list
     print example_features[0,:] # this accesses the first row of the data the ':' indicates 'all columns'
     print example_output[0] # and the corresponding output

     ----> 8     feature_matrix = features_sframe.to_numpy()
     NameError: global name 'features_sframe' is not defined
```

The script above was written by the course authors, so I believe there is something I'm doing wrong

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your parameter is called `data_sframe` but you are trying to coerce `features_sframe` to a `numpy` matrix. Where does `features_sframe` come from? Might that be the issue here?

Comment: Thank your reply @Abdou , however, I don´t think that is a problem, because I saw other guys work posted online and this script has worked perfectly. I believe should be something related with the version of my `graphlab` or my `numpy`. Features (`sqft_living`) is one column from my data frame called `sales`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to complete the function `get_numpy_data` before running it, that's why you are getting an error. Follow the instructions in the original function, which actually are:

```
def get_numpy_data(data_sframe, features, output):
    data_sframe['constant'] = 1 # this is how you add a constant column to an SFrame
    # add the column 'constant' to the front of the features list so that we can extract it along with the others:
    features = ['constant'] + features # this is how you combine two lists
    # select the columns of data_SFrame given by the features list into the SFrame features_sframe (now including constant):

    # the following line will convert the features_SFrame into a numpy matrix:
    feature_matrix = features_sframe.to_numpy()
    # assign the column of data_sframe associated with the output to the SArray output_sarray

    # the following will convert the SArray into a numpy array by first converting it to a list
    output_array = output_sarray.to_numpy()
    return(feature_matrix, output_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `graphlab` assignment instructions have you convert from `graphlab` to `pandas` and then to `numpy`. You could just skip the the `graphlab` parts and use `pandas` directly. (This is explicitly allowed in the homework description.)

First, read in the data files.

```
import pandas as pd

dtype_dict = {'bathrooms':float, 'waterfront':int, 'sqft_above':int, 'sqft_living15':float, 'grade':int, 'yr_renovated':int, 'price':float, 'bedrooms':float, 'zipcode':str, 'long':float, 'sqft_lot15':float, 'sqft_living':float, 'floors':str, 'condition':int, 'lat':float, 'date':str, 'sqft_basement':int, 'yr_built':int, 'id':str, 'sqft_lot':int, 'view':int}
sales = pd.read_csv('data//kc_house_data.csv', dtype=dtype_dict)
train_data = pd.read_csv('data//kc_house_train_data.csv', dtype=dtype_dict)
test_data = pd.read_csv('data//kc_house_test_data.csv', dtype=dtype_dict)
```

The convert to `numpy` function then becomes

```
def get_numpy_data(df, features, output):
    df['constant'] = 1

    # add the column 'constant' to the front of the features list so that we can extract it along with the others
    features = ['constant'] + features

    # select the columns of data_SFrame given by the features list into the SFrame features_sframe
    features_df = pd.DataFrame(**FILL IN THE BLANK HERE WITH YOUR CODE**)

    # cast the features_df into a numpy matrix
    feature_matrix = features_df.as_matrix()

    etc.
```

The remaining code should be the same (since you only work with the `numpy` versions for the rest of the assignment).